# Creating field with difference between areas of two layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, area, expression, differences

In QGIS how can I get the difference between the areas of two layers through field calculator? And is there a way to automatize it so every time a new feature is added the difference updates?

- Layer 1 = Big polygon
- Layer 2 = small polygons inside polygon in layer 1

The "difference" field in this case would be an attribute of the Layer 1.
The area attribute in both layers are virtual fields (`$area`)

I thought putting a code in the Default Value of the field in Attribute Form and check 'Apply default Value on update' but I just can't write the code, maybe something with aggregate?

The image bellow shows a schematic representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expression in the Field Calculator of layer 1:

```
$area - array_sum(overlay_contains('layer_2', "area"))
```

---

Explanation:

With [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains), you get all the polygons from layer 2 that are inside the current feature of layer 1. With `"area"`, you refer to the attribute with this name. The result is an array, thus to add all the areas of all polygons inside the current feature, use [`array_sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sum), then subtract this from the area of the current feature.